# Projection Error in Explorer for ArcGIS

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-online, arcgis-online-basemaps, arcgis-explorer

When I look at the map "Prefeitura de Manaus (Gestão de Obras - SEMINF)" on ArcGIS online, it shows perfect alignment between the lot lines (in blue) and the satellite basemap:

[image]

However, when I look at the same map in the Explorer for ArcGIS app, there appears to be a distortion in the projection of the lots onto the satellite map, with all lots being misalligned by a few meters:

[image]

Does anyone know why the projections differ between the app and online and if there is a way to correct the projection in the app?

Comment: Which coordinate-systems information is each of the datasets in?

Comment: Online, I see this for the information of the Lots layer:

Comment: XMin: 349009.7803
YMin: 4650597.7479
XMax: 465659.8451
YMax: 4766164.1061
Spatial Reference: PROJCS["semef",GEOGCS["GCS_South_American_1969",DATUM["D_South_American_1969",SPHEROID["GRS_1967_Truncated",6378160.0,298.25]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",400000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",5000000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-60.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.999996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

Comment: I'm not sure how to find the coordinate system on the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Satellite data in the two screenshots is different. The top screenshot is the Ortophoto layer and the bottom screenshot is the AGOL Imagery layer. All of the data in the WebMap (including Ortophoto) is shifted because it is in a different Datum than WGS 84 and has not had the correct transformation applied in order to be displayed on top of Web Mercator base maps. The bottom screenshot was likely taken before the Ortophoto layer finished loading. Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is there anyway to correct the projection in the app so that the layers align properly?